# Beamer: Highlight text in bold (math mode)

Tags: beamer, math-mode

I want to highlight a certain part of a formula from one slide to the next.

I'm looking for something similar to

```
Non bold on slide 1 \textbf<2>{this is bold on slide 2}
```

just in math mode.

Comment: Do `\alt` or `temporal` work in mathmode? Hint: Helping would be easier if you provided a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like the `\alt`. In some cases you might even have the desire to have something maybe gray just to this special moment, and then it only needs to be there. Maybe the command `\temporal` can be helping:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Non bold on slide 1 \textbf<2>{this is bold on slide 2}

i am the \alt<1,3>{standard}{alternative}:
$\alt<1,3>{a}{\mathbf{a}}$

\temporal<2>{before: $a$}{right now: $\mathbf{a}$}{after: $a$}

pdfpage: \thepage
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @bonanza I added the `temporal` command, maybe you find that useful, too.