# A beamer fade out-fade in effect?

Tags: beamer, presentations, examples

In some of my slides, especially the technical ones, I would like to keep the bottom of the previous slide, preferably somewhat faded, as the <s>bottom</s> top of the next slide as I start introducing new material so that readers could keep in sight the flow of ideas and notations. In a sense, like when one writes on the blackboard. Ànd erases one line at a time...

For instance, something like an automated version of the following...

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,professionalfonts]{beamer}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
This is an important theorem due to Euler:

\pause
\bigskip
\begin{block}{Theorem}
If $n$ and $a$ are coprime positive integers, then
$$
    a^{\varphi (n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}
$$
where $\varphi(n)$ is Euler's totient function
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
There is a direct proof: Let $R = \{x_1, x_2, ..., x_{\varphi(n)}\}$ be a reduced residue system
(mod $n$) and let $a$ be any integer coprime to $n$. The proof hinges on the fundamental fact that
multiplication by $a$ permutes the $x_i$:

\only<1>{
\textcolor{lightgray}{\begin{block}{Theorem}
\textcolor{lightgray}{If $n$ and $a$ are coprime positive integers, then
$$
    a^{\varphi (n)} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}
$$
where $\varphi(n)$ is Euler's totient function}
\end{block}}}
\only<2>{
in other words if $ax_j ≡ ax_k (\pmod n)$ then $j = k$. That is, the sets $R$ and $aR = \{ax_1, ax_2, ..., ax_{\varpi(n)}\}$,
considered as sets of congruence classes $(\pmod n)$, are identical
so the product of all the numbers in $R$ is congruent $(\pmod n)$ to the product of all the numbers in $aR$:
$$
    \prod_{i=1}^{\varphi(n)} x_i \equiv \prod_{i=1}^{\varphi(n)}
    ax_i \equiv a^{\varphi(n)}\prod_{i=1}^{\varphi(n)} x_i \pmod{n},
$$
and using the cancellation law to cancel the $x_i$'s gives Euler's theorem:
$$
    a^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1 \pmod{n}.
$$}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you just mean something as simple as `\pause` or more complex thing? Like [temporal](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158928/beamer-highlight-text-in-bold-math-mode/158933#158933)

Comment: I think you can achieve the desired effect with the beamer overlays specs but a possible solution would be relative to the actual content of your slide, so you need to post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to work with. Anyway, welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some points:

- You can use `\usebackgroundtemplate` and `pdfpages` to insert slides as background.
- to indicate the *pervious slide*, `\beamer@startpageofframe` is useful.
- use `mdframed` and `tikz` to block the pervious slide.
- Since it is dangerous to insert a pdf into itself, I created two files `199832-main.tex` and `199832-material.pdf`. They are almost identical except that in `199832-material.pdf` the line begins with `\usebackgroundtemplate` is commented out.

So the 10th pages are as follows:

[image] [image]

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=white,framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[settings={\tikzset{every picture/.style={opacity=0.95}}}]{mymdframed}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}\begin{mymdframed}
        \only<+->{AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA \\ AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA \\}
        \only<+->{AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA \\ AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA \\}
        \only<+->{AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA \\ AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA \\}
        \only<+->{AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA \\ AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA \\}
    \end{mymdframed}\end{frame}

\makeatletter
\newcount\my@frameendprev
\usebackgroundtemplate{\vbox{\my@frameendprev\beamer@startpageofframe\advance\my@frameendprev by-1\includepdf[pages={\the\my@frameendprev}]{199832-material.pdf}}}
\makeatother

    \begin{frame}\begin{mymdframed}
        \only<+->{BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB \\ BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB \\}
        \only<+->{BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB \\ BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB \\}
        \only<+->{BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB \\ BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB \\}
        \only<+->{BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB \\ BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB BBBBBBBB \\}
    \end{mymdframed}\end{frame}

    \begin{frame}\begin{mymdframed}
        \only<+->{CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC \\ CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC \\}
        \only<+->{CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC \\ CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC \\}
        \only<+->{CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC \\ CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC \\}
        \only<+->{CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC \\ CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC CCCCCCCC \\}
    \end{mymdframed}\end{frame}

    \begin{frame}\begin{mymdframed}
        \only<+->{DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD \\ DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD \\}
        \only<+->{DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD \\ DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD \\}
        \only<+->{DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD \\ DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD \\}
        \only<+->{DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD \\ DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD \\}
    \end{mymdframed}\end{frame}

\end{document}
```